# SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Tags: python

Написал свой первый код(калькулятор), теперь надо чтобы если человек после выбранной функции написал -, то у него повторился код с 1 строки. Мне выдаёт ошибку:

> SyntaxError: 'return' outside function.

Что можно придумать,что бы код повторялся с 1 строки?

Код:

```
    from colorama import init
 
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
init()
print (Fore.BLACK )
print (Back.WHITE )
k = "-"
while k == "-":
  #Основные переменные
  what = input("Что делаем?(+,-,*,/,**):")
  a = float(input ("Введите первое число:") )
  b = float(input ("Введите второе число:") )
  if what =="+":
    d = float(input ("Введите третье число:") )
    c= a + b + d
    print ("Результат " + str(c) )
  elif what =="-":
    d = float(input ("Введите третье число:") )
    c= a - b - d
    print ("Результат " + str(c) )
  elif what =="*":
    d = float(input ("Введите третье число:") )
    c= a * b * d
    print ("Результат " + str(c) )
  elif what =="/":
    c= a/b
    print ("Результат " + str(c) )
  elif what =="**":
    c= a **b 
    print ("Результат " + str(c) )
  else:
    print("Выбрана неверная функция!!!")
  k =input("Вы хотите выйти?:")
  while k == "-" or k == "нет":
```

Comment: Замените первый `while` последним.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка возникает, потому что вы указали инструкцию `return` вне функции, а она допускается только в функции.

В питоне нет великолепной инструкции `goto`, так что вот так:

```
from colorama import init
 
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
init()
print (Fore.BLACK )
print (Back.WHITE )
k = "-"
while k == "-":
  #Основные переменные
  what = input("Что делаем?(+,-,*,/,**):")
  a = float(input ("Введите первое число:") )
  b = float(input ("Введите второе число:") )
  if what =="+":
    d = float(input ("Введите третье число:") )
    c= a + b + d
    print ("Результат " + str(c) )
  elif what =="-":
    d = float(input ("Введите третье число:") )
    c= a - b - d
    print ("Результат " + str(c) )
  elif what =="*":
    d = float(input ("Введите третье число:") )
    c= a * b * d
    print ("Результат " + str(c) )
  elif what =="/":
    c= a/b
    print ("Результат " + str(c) )
  elif what =="**":
    c= a **b 
    print ("Результат " + str(c) )
  else:
    print("Выбрана неверная функция!!!")
  k =input("Вы хотите выйти?:")
```

Comment: Неплохо бы добавить, почему он получил `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function.`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin так в ошибке же сказано явно: 'return' вне функции

Comment: Это нам с вами понятно, а человек не понимает и поэтому спрашивает что это и как ему поступить

Comment: @AlexanderChernin добавил

Comment: а как теперь сделать так,что бы если человек ответил нет,то код начинался заново?

Comment: @Никита ну так вместо "-" поставьте "нет", либо если надо и "-", и "нет", то поставьте `while k == "-" or k == "нет"`

Comment: @Никита `while` - это цикл, сначала проверяется условие, а дальше все инструкции после него выполняются, потом опять проверяется условие и если оно опять выполнилось, то снова и так далее

Comment: добавил while k == "-" or k == "нет":

Comment: File "test.py", line 35                                        ^ SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: теперь эта ошибка

Comment: @Никита задайте новый вопрос, отредактировав код и ошибку так, как сделано сейчас в вопросе, не буду же я гадать, какая сейчас у вас 35 строка

Comment: отредактировал код

Comment: @Никита вместо `while k == "-":` поставьте `while k == "-" or k == "нет":`, а снизу удалите

Comment: хм,та же ошибка,после while k == "-" or k == "нет": надо что то ещё добавить?

Comment: @Никита откатите этот вопрос к предыдущему и задайте новый вопрос, так мы бесконечно может в комментариях гадать, что у вас происходит

Comment: @Никита Замените первый `while` последним, так чтобы у Вас остался всего один `while` в начале кода.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def func(exp, mes, arg=''):
    while not re.match(exp, arg): arg = input(mes)
    return arg

out = False
while not out:
    num1 = func(r'^\d+$', 'Enter first number: ')
    act  = func(r'^[-+*/]$', 'Enter operator: ')
    num2 = func(r'^\d+$', 'Enter second number: ')

    result = eval(num1 + act + num2)

    print(f'{num1} {act} {num2} = {result}')
    out = True if input('Exit? Y/N ').lower() == 'y' else False
```

Comment: Где-то я видел этот код недавно... Энивей, вряд ли ТС его поймёт без обид

Comment: @dimon Да, буквально недавно я выкладывал ответ на похожий вопрос по такому же горе-калькулятору )